# Vacuum blows Breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker, vacuum

My Meile vacuum has all of a sudden started blowing circuit breakers.  It does not matter what outlet in the house I plug my vac into the breaker blows.  When I plug the vac in there is usually a spark at the plug.  I have had the vac for over 20 years with not problems. Any ideals

Comment: getting a new one isn't an option?

Comment: Do the breakers have TEST buttons on them? Are you plugging the vacuum in with the power switch on?  Can you post a nameplate for the vacuum, and are these 15A or 20A breakers it is tripping?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your vacuum has a short in it, and your breakers are saving you, but if you try hard enough you might be able to start a fire. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Check where the cord goes into the plug or where it goes into the unit... those are stress points.

Comment: Seeing as it's 20 years old, the motor of the vacuum very likely died (because of wear, moving parts etc) and created a short in the process. Just replace the vacuum

Comment: The fact that you've had it for 20 years without problems does not mean it's the greatest vac on earth and the problem must be elsewhere. It means it's 20 years old and outlived it's useful life. The vac is broken and all of your circuit breakers are doing their job by protecting you from your broken vac. Throw it out & get a new one.

Comment: FYI to the responders, Meile is a high-end (expensive) German vacuum, so it is understandable if the OP is reluctant to just go buy another. Nevertheless, I agree with the answers.

Comment: @brhans, my little brother has our grandmothers Kirby, it is over 40 years old and parts are not very expensive I have fixed it up for him in the past, just because it is 20 years old is not a reason to discard it.

Comment: "When I plug the vac in there is usually a spark at the plug." Well, if the common ingredient in this situation is the vacuum and no other appliance exhibits this behavior then you should definitely fix or replace the vacuum before continuing to use it.

Answer (score 3):

If your vacuum is blowing each breaker in your house, it is drawing way too much power, and you need to fix it before you have an electrical fire to deal with.

For a 20 year old appliance, I would look at the power cord, the brushes and the bearings, as failures in each of those could cause the problem you are experiencing.  Your problem could be something different, like a shorted winding in the motor.  This can happen when the motor overheats, which can happen when using long extension cords, and therefore having voltage drops with increased heating in the windings.  On power head units, sometimes the wires running through the handle will chafe and that can cause a frank short, but that is more rare.

Regardless of what the cause is, you should discontinue testing relying on the circuit breaker, and fix or replace the appliance.

Comment: Depending on the type of motor brushes are a good thing to check, any bad spots in the cord or kinks close to the strain relief or plug are normal places for damage. , with it unplugged try turning the beater bar and make something is not stuck in the blower that creates the vacuum in older uprights the motor is directly connected to the blower then the belt to the beater bar, if something is stuck in the blades it can cause this as a 3rd possible cause.+

Comment: @EdBeal great point on something jamming a blower.  However for many motors this would not cause a breaker blow.

Comment: A brushed universal will cause this, I had a slightly different problem when a primer blew the blades up , the motor was good. The wife was just a little upset, mostly because the small explosion scared the pee out of her and the girls thought it was funny so I was in big trouble.

Comment: @EdBeal, wow, that sounds like such a cool trick!!!  I am having fun thinking of the possibilities...

Comment: I was banned from reloading in the house, large magnum primers for make quite a pop, my son used to find them and take them outside and hit them with a hammer, I thought his friends had bought fire crackers. Lucky they were putting them on a old stump.

Comment: note: "drawing way too much power" = "short circuit" colloquially

Answer (score 2):

This is an open-and-shut case of a vacuum cleaner that needs to go to the repair shop.  It could be a variety of problems, including junk sucked into the motor.

A quality vacuum should be repairable.